# How to add a character to the last third place of a string?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a column with numbers with various lengths such as 50055, 1055,155 etc. How can I add a decimal before the last 2nd place of each so that it would be 500.55, 10.55, and 1.55?

I tried using replace by finding the last 2 numbers and replace it with .||last 2 number. That doesn't always work because of a possibility of multiple repetition of the same sequence in the same string.

```
replace(round(v_num/2),substr(round(v_num/2),-2),'.'||substr(round(v_num/2),-2))
```

Comment: Are your values **numbers** or **strings**? You say "numbers" but what you show looks very much like manipulating strings. For example: can your input look like 0003932? Then it is most certainly a string, not a number. Do you need the output from 100 to look like 1.00, and not 1? Then you are most definitely talking about strings, not numbers. Please clarify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would divide by 100:

```
select v_num / 100
```

You can convert this into a string, if you want.